Variables in Dockerfile not expanded when run through Ansible's community.docker.docker_compose
I finally found out, that I need to run the CMD in shell mode, since I have variables in the command line (as stated here : How can I use a variable inside a Dockerfile CMD?)
The CMD in the Dockerfile is:
CMD ["sh", "-c", "gunicorn -w=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:7004 --certfile=/data/cert/${HOSTNAME}.crt --keyfile=/data/cert/${HOSTNAME}.key main:app"]

With this,  docker-compose up -d is running fine.
But, when running the same Dockerfile from an Ansible playbook, then the variables are not being expanded. I use the module community.docker.docker_compose.
The log output of the container with the gunicorn startup is:
  # ...
  keyfile: /data/cert/.key
  certfile: /data/cert/.crt
  # ...

Ansible output is
ok: [host.example.com] => {
    "output": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "services": {
            "my_service": {
                "my_service": {
                    "cmd": [
                        "sh",
                        "-c",
                        "gunicorn -w=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:7004 --certfile=/data/cert/${HOSTNAME}.crt --keyfile=/data/cert/${HOSTNAME}.key main:app"
                    ],

How can I convince Ansible to expand these environment variables?

That last output seems fine to me – when /bin/sh is run with the -c option, the shell will expand the ${HOSTNAME} reference in its string argument.  That is, variable expansion will happen inside the container after it is created, and it won't be visible to the Ansible management system.  Are you expecting different output?

(What sets the $HOSTNAME environment variable inside the container?)

community.docker.docker_compose uses a Python module to wrap compose command, you might not have a shell when running it, which might explain why. Have you tested with the not-deprecated one, namely community.docker.docker_compose_v2 module, rather?

I had to pass the variables from the playbook to docker-compose.yml and from there to the Dockerfile. Now it is working with community.docker.docker_compose and community.docker.docker_compose_v2. So the hint 'might not have a shell when running' was pointing me to the right direction. Thanks for this.
